# Using $.ajax post to send data to node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, send

First of all my questions might get you relate to others but I have got many solutions but they did not work. So I am posting my problem hope you guys can help me.!

I have created two file posts.ejs and app.js(routes implemented in this file).

**Post.ejs**

Ajax call:-

```
 function SaveLocalNews(postData, cb) {

        var headerSetting = {
            "api-key": 1,
            "UDID": getUDID(),
            "device-type": getDeviceType(),
            "Authorization": "Authorization"
        };
        var requestMedia = $.ajax({
            url: "/posts",
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            headers: headerSetting
        });

        requestMedia.done(function (data) {
            if (data.status) {
                alert_message("success");
            } else {
                alert_message("fail" + "success");
                // TODO: Handle not uploaded media
            }
            return;
        });
        requestMedia.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            // TODO: Handle not uploaded media
            alert_message("fail");
            return
        });
```

}

**App.js**

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
mysql = require("mysql");

var session = require('express-session');

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post("/posts",  function (req, res) {
//I am not getting body/data what I have passed in ajax request. 
    console.log(req.body); // Output:-  {}
});
```

I hope you clear with my problem.

Comment: show us the file `express`, also show server side code

Comment: @Black OP is using node.js, `App.js` *is* the server side code

Comment: @RohitasBehera what does that have to do with the server side not accessing the post vars?

Comment: OP, inside `SaveLocalNews` can you do `console.log(postData)`? What is the output? Does it log the data you expect?

Comment: okay...requestMedia.done( is never beign reached...could you check your network xhr request

Comment: @RohitasBehera the issue is in the route on the server side, not the `done` method not being called, look at the comment in the code

Comment: OP, can you try adding `app.use( bodyParser.json() );` before your route?

Comment: @DelightedD0D inside SaveLocalNews method I am getting the postData, but when I am sending it to serverside to my app.js file I am not getting data.

I have also tried app.use( bodyParser.json() ); but still not getting data

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to make at least few changes:

### On the server side

add `app.use( bodyParser.json());`

---

### On the client side

Update your ajax to:

```
  var requestMedia = $.ajax({
        url: "/posts",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false, 
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: headerSetting
    });
```

---

#### Reasons for these changes

I would change the ajax to `data: JSON.stringify(postData),` instead of using `processData: false,`. *I think* the two are basically equivalent, I just prefer this way personally.

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. *It is converted to a query string,* **if not already a string**. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

---

change your ajax to `contentType: 'application/json',` since `false` will cause it to set no content type header and might be causing node to not see the post body correctly.

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
>
> Type: Boolean or String
>
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to  $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header.

---

You also want to change `dataType: false,` to `dataType: 'json',` since your done handler is looking for `data.status` which means you are in fact expecting json to be returned (even though your server side code doesnt seem to do that yet)

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

---

If you updated to use `JSON.stringify(postData)`, remove the `processData: false,`.

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> processData (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Comment: Could you please tell me, how can I send the data back to ajax call, because I am not getting data their even after writing res.send(data).